# How to display section of a torus only

Tags: modeling

I have a torus object from which i only want to see a certain section? like a quarter of a ring.

The section should be at an arbitrary given angle and should be changeable later on.

Comment: Did you try the boolean modifier already? If the objects share 2 materials in the same slots you can remove the areas where the object is cut by making one material transparent and not traceable.

Comment: yeah the boolean operator does the trick, thanks!